# SSRS need to get URL to skip the parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with one parameter to choose from a dropdown with values like polk,collier.I would like to get the URL where I can skip the step of and get the pdf for each of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Think this link from the Microsoft Website may help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

E.g. In the case below - ReportMonth and ReportYear are parameters with values passed in.

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

This link will help you with the PDF export:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF
```

So for your example I would do something like:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/yourreport&YourParameter=yourvalue&rs:Format=PDF
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing from the sound of it is to set up the report with that Parameter selecting all values by default, that way you can simply design the URL without specifying a value for the parameter, and it will automatically run your report for all of the values you told it to select by default.